# C++ type casting interpretation

Tags: c++, pointers, types, casting

I am porting an C++ embedded code and stumble on this piece of code:

```
*(AppCHRONOAMPCfg_Type**)pCfg = &AppCHRONOAMPCfg;
```

What the first and the double asterics mean? I guessed is about a type casting
For what I understand this line allocates the memory space for the pCfg, am I right?

Comment: `*reinterpret_cast<AppCHRONOAMPCfg_Type**>(pCfg) = &AppCHRONOAMPCfg;` might be clearer...

Comment: Double asterisks means "pointer to a pointer to a thing", sometimes also called "handle to a thing" (where handle is a pointer-to-a-pointer).

Answer (score 1):

There is no allocation, just a reinterpretation and an assignment (to whatever `pCfg` happens to point to).

The first asterisk is a dereferencing asterisk; the double ones belong to the type `AppCHRONOAMPCfg_Type**`, which is a pointer to a pointer (and is in a cast, as you suspect).

More explicit step by step version:

```
AppCHRONOAMPCfg_Type** configuration = reinterpret_cast<AppCHRONOAMPCfg_Type**>(pCfg);
*configuration = &AppCHRONOAMPCfg;
```

Comment: Aside: there might also be a `const_cast` in there too, we can't know